# Allow only given parameters value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I my RoR (v 6.1) application (only API) i have route

```
resources :cars
```

This is valid URL:

```
http://localhost/cars
```

To find cars with fuel pb95  i use:

```
http://localhost/cars?fuel=pb95
```

Only pb95, pb98, gas are allowed for fuel?

How do I limit the ability to specify a fuel type outside of the list?
If someone enters a value outside the list should I display that this value cannot be used, or display that there are no cars that meet this condition?

Whitch approach looks better?

Comment: You can use activemodel validations for this. `validates :fuel, inclusion: ["pb96", "pb98"]`

Comment: Yes it works for crete method, but not for index.

Comment: Works for index too, if you use form objects.

Comment: I.ve insert your line to model, and it doesnt work.

Comment: It is only API, not full rails application. This line works for create model. I want to display error message if somebody use fuel kind not from list.

Comment: Of course it doesn't work, because in my proposal validations live in form objects: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/activemodel-form-objects. There are more articles on this design pattern.

Comment: Yes, i know what you are toking about. I need limit value of fuel params only to given values. Not limit, but if someone send request with bad fuel value ex: 'xxx', it shoul see error message.

Comment: Sounds like you _don't_ know what I'm talking about. It is a way to exactly what you want. Granted, the article I linked to doesn't cover your scenario _exactly_, but it should've been enough to give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options for how to handle this.

One approach would be to check the fuel type in your controller, and render an error response if they pass an invalid fuel type.

Another approach would be via route constraints. Instead of using query params, you can use special routes to receive your params:

```
get 'cars/:fuel_type', to: "cars#index", fuel_type: /(pb95|pb98)/, as: :cars_with_fuel_type
```

This way, if an invalid fuel type is provided, the route wont match and they'll get a 404.

If you want something other than a 404, then the first option gives you more control over the error response.

Comment: OK, i have gone with the first one